# Рисование текста в SFML и сохранение изображения

Tags: c++, изображения, sfml

Пытаюсь вывести текст на изображение с использованием SFML. Не удаётся вывести текст по координатам (x,y) и после сохранения изображение получается зеркальным и перевёрнутым. Не пойму, что делаю не так?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("SpaceGrotesk-Medium.ttf");
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("Hello world");
    text.setCharacterSize(90);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);


    sf::Texture img;
    img.loadFromFile("image.jpg");
    sf::Sprite sprite(img);

    sf::RenderTexture texture;
    texture.create(765, 480);
    texture.draw(sprite);
    texture.draw(text);

    texture.getTexture().copyToImage().saveToFile("new_file.jpg");

    return 0;
}
```

Исходное изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итоговое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не хватает вызова `texture.display()` после рисования на ней

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно быть, смотрите ссылки:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22424124

https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11178.msg77236

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)